# Add EPSG:404000 WMS to OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, wms, epsg-40400

I am currently trying to add an EPSG:404000 WMS to my OpenLayer map. The map is using EPSG:4326 for it's projection. When I tried to use the following code, the url returns a 1x1 WMS, when it should have been 1293 x 500. Here's the code that I am using:

```
const KmlProjection = new Projection({code: 'EPSG:404000'})
const addKml = () => {
            const layer = new ImageLayer({
                // extent: mapExtent,
                source: new ImageWMS({
                    url: GEO_SERVICE_API_URL,
                    imageLoadFunction: customLoader,
                    params: {
                        LAYERS: "cite:PALM_COUNTING",
                        VERSION: '1.3.0',
                        FORMAT: 'image/png',
                    },
                    projection: KmlProjection,
                     ratio: 1,
                }),
                // visible: false,
                properties: {
                    type: 'kml',
                },
            })
    
            myMap?.addLayer(layer)
    }
const initMap = () => {
    const newMap = new Map({
      interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([new DragRotateAndZoom()]),
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
          visible: true,
                    properties: {
                        type: 'raster',
                    }
        }),
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new View({
        center: [113.9213, -0.7893],
        zoom: 5,
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        showFullExtent: true,
      }),
    })
    setMyMap(newMap)
  }
```

Comment: EPSG:404000 is some custom projection and not known to generic WMS clients.

Comment: If you have no proj4 definition for the projection OpenLayers cannot reproject it and you must also use it as the view projection as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-no-proj.html

Comment: EPSG:404000 is defined as _"A two-dimensional wild card coordinate system with x, y axis in metres"_ (see https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html). As @Mike wrote, you need proj4 definition for it to be used in OpenLayers.

Comment: see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/epsg-40400/info

Answer (score 2):

404000 is a made-up code, a practical joke based on "HTTP 404, not found", that GeoServer uses when no projection information is found in your source data (GeoServer is also used in applications where no actual projection is available or makes sense, like publishing planimetry or random images in a tiled client).

If you can, go to GeoServer and set up a valid EPSG code for the data instead.